# Key exchange protocol and digital signatures

Tags: encryption, cryptography, digital-signature, public-key-encryption

I am a beginner to coding and encryption standards...
I have this task assigned in a course I am following

**Design and implement a key exchange protocol. Include digital signatures in the protocol for authentication.**

Does implementing the Diffie Hellman algorithm covers both parts as in key exchange + digital signature ? or only the key exchange part ?
If so what should I do ?

Comment: Only key exchange...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Only Key exchange.

You can read [this paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1278320/) about the use of Diffie-Hellman in a Digital Signature Algorithm. Its title: Integrating Diffie-Hellman key exchange into the digital signature algorithm (DSA).

And [this another paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2495338): Use of Digital Signature with Diffie Hellman Key Exchange and AES Encryption Algorithm to Enhance Data Security in Cloud Computing.

As a suggestion, you can use [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman) as a secure key exchange algorithm and [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) as a digital signature algorithm.

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you think it is a good answer, please mark it as the answer.